# Tool to generate a GUI (WinForms or WPF) from a class

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Say we've got a class like

```
public class Doer 
{
    public int Timeout {get;set;}
    public string DoIt(string input)
    {
        string toReturn;
        // Do something that involves a Timeout
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Is there a tool that would create a Form or Control for prototyping this class? The GUI might have a NumericUpDown control with a label of "Timeout" and a GroupBox with a TextBox for "input" and a button labeled "DoIt" with an eventhandler that calls `Doer.DoIt` with the Text property of the `input` TextBox and puts the response in another TextBox.

[image: GUI with a NumericUpDown control with a label of "Timeout" and a GroupBox with a TextBox for "input" and a button labeled "DoIt" with an eventhandler that calls Doer.DoIt with the Text property of the input TextBox and puts the response in another TextBox.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[XAML Power Toys](https://web.archive.org/web/20130926051416/http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com:80/xaml-power-toys/) can generate XAML from a model

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.com](http://karlshifflett.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/v31createwpfdatagrid-thumb.jpg?w=553&h=484))</sub>

Comment: You win for WPF. Wish there was an answer for WinForms :-|

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like [Naked Objects](http://nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml) are a good avenue to research. ([Hanselminutes podcast](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=252).)

[Briefly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects):

> The naked objects pattern is defined
>   by three principles:
>
> 1. All business logic should be encapsulated onto the domain objects.
>      This principle is not unique to naked
>      objects: it is just a strong
>      commitment to encapsulation.
> 2. The user interface should be a direct representation of the domain
>      objects, with all user actions
>      consisting, explicitly, of creating or
>      retrieving domain objects and/or
>      invoking methods on those objects.
>      This principle is also not unique to
>      naked objects: it is just a specific
>      interpretation of an object-oriented
>      user interface (OOUI). The original
>      idea in the naked objects pattern
>      arises from the combination of these
>      two, to form the third principle:
> 3. The user interface should be created 100% automatically from the
>      definition of the domain objects. This
>      may be done using several different
>      technologies, including source code
>      generation; implementations of the
>      naked objects pattern to date have
>      favoured the technology of reflection.
>      The naked objects pattern was first
>      described formally in Richard Pawson's
>      PhD thesis[1](http://nakedobjects.net/home/index.shtml) which includes a
>      thorough investigation of various
>      antecedents and inspirations for the
>      pattern including, for example, the
>      Morphic user interface. Naked Objects
>      is commonly contrasted with the
>      model-view-controller pattern.
>      However, the published version of
>      Pawson's thesis (see References)
>      contains a foreword by Trygve
>      Reenskaug, who first formulated the
>      model-view-controller pattern,
>      suggesting that naked objects is
>      closer to the original intent of
>      model-view-controller than many of the
>      subsequent interpretations and
>      implementations.