# GUI Form Building uppon object (like Propertygrid)

Tags: c#, user-interface, design-patterns, object, properties

I am wondering, what the design pattern is, when I have an object and want to be able to edit it in a GUI (dialogue, etc). I'm using C#.NET... Perhaps there are also some integrated features with visual studio 2008?

By using a PropertyGrid, I can attach an object to it (.SelectedObject). What I'm looking for is something similar: to let a gui automatically build about the object which is attached to it.

Any hints are most welcome!
Regards, Greg

Answer (score 0):

**could it be you are looking for a ready-made control library to use?**

It would be simply document-view (possibly in a MVC context if there is also going to be a controller).

The only special part is that you have a particularly dynamic/generic view (control).

If you really insist you could tangentially mention

- observer pattern (for 'observing' the change in selected object)
- visitor pattern (for 'visiting' the properties of the selected object)

but this starting to get in the realm of complete conjecture. I might even say that 'SpaghettiCodePattern' could be used in implementing this. It might, and it doesn't have to be.

**I don't think (there is)/(you are looking) for a design pattern**

Comment: Okay, it is not that I'm especially looking for a design pattern, I was just wondering how this could be accomplished. I'll have a look at the "document-view" you mentioned. So far, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the propertygrid is based on using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general. There is pattern which is called naked object pattern, do you mean something like this?

Also have a look at these:
[Tool to generate a GUI (WinForms or WPF) from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511545/tool-to-generate-a-gui-winforms-or-wpf-from-a-class)