# How to generate edit fields/CRUD-dialogue from a POCO class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In the [Create a One-to-Many Data Entry Form Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb643827) at minute 2, a `DataSet` is used to automatically generate detail fields (`Textboxes`, `Comboboxes`) for a data record.

Similiar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511545/tool-to-generate-a-gui-winforms-or-wpf-from-a-class) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131821/code-generating-a-winforms-form-from-a-c-sharp-poco-class), I am looking for a way to scaffold a windows forms CRUD dialog from a POCO.

Does anyone know if and how generating CRUD-dialogues from POCO can be achieved in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Browsing i came across [winformgenerator](https://winformgenerator.codeplex.com/) I have not tried it yet but i looks like it could be a solution for creating CRUD-dialogues.